# git checkout branch from remote

Tags: git

I searched a lot in stackoverflow, people saying the way to checkout remote branch, you do:

```
git checkout -b test origin/test
```

-b means create a new branch

I am confused why can't I just do:

```
git checkout test origin/test
```

I tried to do this command, it went into a detached state.

I have these questions:

1. What's the difference between them?
2. Why don't I need the "-b" when checkout from mainline?
3. Why git developer designed in this way that it is not very intuitive, why not just make "-b" default behaviour?

Comment: `git checkout test origin/test` should produce and error unless branch `test` contains a valid path `origin/test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the first case you created a branch called `test`, in the second, you didn't.  If you don't already have a branch called `test` with a path called `origin/test` in it, that command shouldn't work at all.
2. You don't need `-b` unless you want to create a branch.  Just checking out a branch doesn't require the `-b` as you noticed.
3. Just a design decision, I guess.  If you don't like it, you can easily make an alias or a macro to do what you want.

Comment: If I checkout without "-b", am I still be able to do commits and push?

Comment: Yes, that should work just fine.  `git checkout -b` is just shorthand for a combination `git checkout` and `git branch`, really.  The documentation has good information.

Comment: When I checkout without "-b", it says it went into a detached state. It didn't work for me.

Comment: Is it a local branch?  If not, you're going to have a detached HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

If remote branch `origin/test` exists,

do a `git pull origin` first which will update your remotes. If `test` did not already exist, then the following message should be seen on this command

```
From <project url>
 * [new branch]      test -> origin/test
```

`git checkout test`  should suffice to create and checkout branch named `test` that is tracking remote branch `origin/test`

The output of above command is :
`Branch test set up to track remote branch test from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'test'`

My git version:

$>`git --version`

git version 1.7.10.2